# What function/method is default when running python -m command in Command Prompt or PowerShell?

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, cmd

Within the Python shell if I were to type the following code

```
import pydoc
pydoc.help(print)
```

ot would return info on the print function.

Now if I wanted to access this module *outside* the Python shell, for example in either PowerShell or the Command Prompt in Windows, I would type the following command:

```
python -m pydoc print
```

which returns the same info as the previous command that I typed.

Now I understand that within the Python shell that `.help` is a method of `pydoc` that I call with a parameter of `print`. Outside the shell with `python -m` it's specifying to run a Python module (in this case `pydoc`).

But what confuses me is how does `pydoc` know what to do with the `print` parameter? How does it know which method to use?

Comment: Whatever the relevant module defines as its entrypoint - in this case a function named `cli`, per https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bb2dcf1c7996c9da3372b89c1759c94ed567b298/Lib/pydoc.py#L2841-L2842. That then access the command line arguments using [`getopt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getopt.html).

Answer (score 2):

When you run a script as a top level module (which is what happens when you do `python -m pydoc print`) its `__name__` will be `"__main__"` - thus the very common piece of code: `if __name__ == '__main__'` - this `if` will not be true when importing the module, so anything in it will not execute.

Now that we know how to detect when a module is run as a top level, we can write a piece of code that will do things like take CLI arguments using standard methods of `sys.argv` etc. and put it after mentioned `if` and we have our own behaviour for `python -m <module-name> <arguments>`

Answer (score 0):

**Pydoc** is a documentation library that *generates* documentation from Python modules. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pydoc.html)

> For modules, classes, functions and methods, the displayed documentation is derived from the **docstring** (i.e. the `__doc__` attribute) of the object, and recursively of its documentable members. If there is **no docstring**, pydoc tries to obtain a description from the **block of comment lines** just above the definition of the class, function or method in the source file, or at the top of the module.

So basically, you can say that `pydoc` tries to use the documentation provided by the module's methods themselves, or if it does not find a *docstring*, it tries to read the *comments* above these module's methods. Finally, it does this for all the methods, classes, functions, parameters inside a module, and prints it to the terminal, or browser.